# phpMyAdmin - Fatal error: Class 'ImportXml' not found

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

After a lot of searching I failed to find any mention to the following error.

> phpMyAdmin - Fatal error: Class 'ImportXml' not found in
>   /var/www/......libraries/plugin_interface.lib.php on line 74

The error occurs when I select **import** in phpMyAdmin in order to import a backup of a database. The only thing that gets displayed is this error message. The version of phpMyAdmin is **4.0.0** and the server runs **php 5.2.6-1+lenny16**

Anyone ever had similar issues? I found some info on how to import the database using PHP but I don't feel very confident right now.

Also, is there a way to selectively update entries in a table of the database with data from the backup, without importing the whole backup, using PHP?

Answer (score 1):

> phpMyAdmin - Fatal error: Class 'ImportXml' not found in
>   /var/www/......libraries/plugin_interface.lib.php on line 74

Seems like `libXML` is not a part of `PHP 5.2.17` on your version of Ubuntu.

The best bet is to attempt to install it via the repository like this:

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml
```

Also, `PHP 5.2.17` is quite out of date. The base level of PHP that is used even in the most conservative setups nowadays is `PHP 5.3`. You should see about getting that server upgraded.

Also, if you have no choice but to stay on `PHP 5.2.17` without `libXML` the best non-administrative user thing you can do is install the last known stable version of phpMyAmdin that worked well on `PHP 5.2.17` which is version `2.11.11.3`. How do I know this? I just remembered I had to install that version on a `PHP 5.1.6` system I threw together in the past few years. You can download it from here:

```
http://freefr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/phpmyadmin/phpMyAdmin/2.11.11.3/phpMyAdmin-2.11.11.3-english.tar.gz
```

If you can get your system administrator to install `php-xml` via `apt-get` you might be able to use newer versions of phpMyAdmin, but at least you know that phpMyAdmin version `2.11.11.3` will work with your older setup.

Comment: That sound promising! Unfortunately I'll have to contact the admin for this... I'll do so and post feedback. Thanks a lot

Comment: Indeed, this is documented in the Requirements section of the phpMyAdmin manual: `To support XML and Open Document Spreadsheet importing, you need PHP 5.2.17 or newer and the libxml <http://www.php.net/libxml> extension.` -- so I don't even think his PHP (changed to 5.2.6 in an edit) will work even with the libXML extension.